# Did Arjun and Subhadra do fire rituals for their marriage?

Tags: mahabharata

Arjun married Subhadra in the manner of [Rakshas Vivah.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23034/how-many-types-of-marriages-are-there-according-to-hindusim)
As he abducted her (though with her consent).

I want to know if there happened any fire rituals for this marriage. Or Arjun just abducted Subhadra (with her consent) and took her home and it was considered as marriage.

Also what was the age of Subhadra at the time of marriage with Arjun.

Answer (score 1):

Arjuna and subhadra were properly married in Dwaraka after Lord Krishna convinced the Yadavas to accept them.

> *Hearing, O monarch, those words of Vasudeva, they did as he directed. **Stopped by them, Arjuna returned to Dwaraka and was united in marriage with Subhadra**. Worshipped by the sons of Vrishni’s race,
> Arjuna, sporting there as he pleased, passed a whole year in Dwaraka.*

- Section CCXXIII, Haranaharana parva, Mahabharata.

Comment: It is written , he was united in marriage. No mention of any rituals. In mbh, most events are described in detail, but here it is not.

Comment: @river - considering that the marriage was conducted in Dwaraka, don't you think Krishna and Balarama would follow proper rituals in conducting the marriage of their dear sister ?

Comment: Rakshas Vivah is a also a type of ritual where the man abduct the woman, and then woman is considered as the wife. It is not anything wrong. Rakshas Vivah is permissible for Kshatriya. I asked this question just to confirm if any further ritual is required or not after abduction. 
Also It is to be noted that such practice is not to be followed in present world as Rakshas Vivah is now illegal just like polygamy is illegal in present world.

Comment: Also since in Rakshas and Gandharva Vivah, kanyadaan obviously can't be performed as it would be a sham. As the girl is not marrying with the consent of her father. So, I am thinking what other rituals can be performed.

Comment: @river - whether the bride is taken by force, or given by consent, the rituals after kanyadaan can still be the same. btw, rakshas vivah itself is of 2 types - one where the bride consents and another where bride does not consent. in all dharmic rajas doing rakshas vivah, it is the first case. even in bhishma's case, as soon as amba's lack of consent was known, she was duly returned.

Comment: @ram In case of Gandharva Vivah, it is explicitly written that this marriage happens without mantra. 
[From Mbh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EA7Pe.jpg)
Dushyant did Gandharva Vivah with Shakuntala, and nowhere it is written that he did any kind of fire rituals like going around the fire.

Comment: @river - yeah, but that is not a rule that they should NOT do fire rituals. the explicit act of sex IS the gandharva vivaha. for rakshasa vivaha, which we are discussing, it doesn't say that there are no rituals